# Last Embarcadero C++Builder with classic compiler

Tags: c++builder

What was the last version of C++Builder to contain the old classic compiler alongside the clang/llvm compiler?

Comment: 10.4 update 2 still includes the classic compiler.

Comment: Small nitpick - NO version of **Borland** C++Builder included a clang-based compiler. Only versions of **Embarcadero** C++Builder do.

Comment: Thanks, @RemyLebeau, my mistake, I edited the answer title to reflect actual question.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation, the latest 11.0 Alexandria version includes both the classic Borland compiler and the newer clang-based compilers:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler#Classic_Compiler

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/C%2B%2B_Compilers

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/BCC32

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, C++ Builder 11.0 contains the classic Borland C++ compiler for Win32 (bcc32.exe) applications. I have been using it since September.